# find the elements of a list in the values of a dictionary and accordingly print the key in tabular form

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this list:

```
list1 = ['float', 'x', 'b', 'a', '*', '+', '=', '50']
```

and this dictionary:

```
combined_dict = {
    'Keyword': ['float', 'int', 'char'],
    'Identifier': ['x', 'b', 'a', 'p', 'n'],
    'Operator': ['*', '+', '=', '-', '/'],
    'Constant': ['50', '100', '20']
}
```

The output should be like:

```
|list    | Type       |
|:------:|:----------:|
|float   | Keyword    |
| x      | Identifier |
| b      | Identifier |
| a      | Identifier |
| *      | Operator   |
| +      | Operator   |
| =      | Operator   |
| 50     | Constant   |
```

So the goal here is to find the elements of `list1` in the values of the dictionary and print the corresponding key. This should be in tabular form as shown.

eg  : `float` from the list is a key of `Keyword` in the dictiornary.

I wasn't really able to design a loop for this!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You're having trouble because your dictionary is backwards. Dictionaries are made to look up keys mapped to values, not the other way around. So transform your dictionary first:

```
lookup_dict = {v: k for k, vals in combined_dict.items() for v in vals}
```

Now the task is trivial:

```
for s in list1:
    print(f'| {s:06s} | {lookup_dict[s]:10s} |')
```

I think you can figure out how to print the header and footer in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of code. For the pretty-printing, a for loop might have been more readable.

```py
# transform combined_dict, to allow lookup by token from list1
lookup = dict(sum((
    [(e, key) for e in value]
    for key, value in combined_dict.items()
), []))

# create list with tokens mapped to their corresponding type
mapped = [(key, lookup[key]) for key in list1]

# making it pretty

# column widths for the table based on longest cell in column
width_list = max((len(elem) for elem in list1))
width_type = max((len(t) for _, t in mapped))

# convert mapped tokens into printable rows
converted = ["|{}|{}|".format(
    i.ljust(width_list), t.ljust(width_type)) for i, t in mapped]

# prepare header and divider of table
header = "|{}|{}|".format(
    "list".ljust(width_list), "type".ljust(width_type))
divider = "|+{}+|+{}+|".format(
    "-" * (width_list - 2), "-" * (width_type - 2))

# merge all table lines into single string and print
print("\n".join([header, divider] + converted))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not sure, what you mean, reading the question, it provides the exact solution wanted.

Comment: But I guess answers should explain the way instead of providing just a solution. I will not add a proper description since @Mad Physicist has already done a better job. I added some more comments to the code, however.

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
combined_dict={'Keyword': ['float','int','char'], 'Identifier': ['x', 'b', 'a','p','n'], 'Operator': ['*', '+', '=','-','/'], 'Constant': ['50','100','20']}
list1=['float', 'x', 'b', 'a', '*', '+', '=', '50'] 
types = []
for fromlistvalue in list1:
    for value in combined_dict:
        if fromlistvalue in combined_dict[value]:
            types.append(value)
df = pd.DataFrame({"list":list1,"Type":types})
```